# SQL Server, How to perform a bulk update of certain fields within single table

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016

SQL Server, How to perform a bulk update of certain fields within single table (orders)?

| order no | comp date | order notes |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1000579 | 01/01/1900 | NULL |
| 1000578 | 01/01/1900 | NULL |
| 1005077 | 01/01/1900 | NULL |
| 1000576 | 01/01/1900 | NULL |
| 1000575 | 01/01/1900 | NULL |
| 1000574 | 01/01/1900 | NULL |
| 1000573 | 01/01/1900 | NULL |
| 1000572 | 01/01/1900 | NULL |
| 1000571 | 01/01/1900 | NULL |

I wish to bulk Update above (not all from the column)  the following order numbers comp (completion) date field and order notes field

order completion date

```
1000579 = 14/08/2020
1000578 = 29/08/2019
1005077 = 02/06/2019
1005706 = 03/06/2019
1005750 = 29/06/2019
1000574 = 25/06/2019
1000573 = 24/07/2019
1000572 = 24/07/2019
1000571 = 03/07/2019
```

order notes

```
1000579 = "bulk update"
1000578 = "bulk update"
1005077 = "bulk update"
1000576 = "bulk update"
1000575 = "bulk update"
1000574 = "bulk update"
1000573 = "bulk update"
1000572 = "bulk update"
1000571 = "bulk update"
```

I have the following to successfully update the first order number, but I need a way to update multiple records. I do not know which method to use

```sql
UPDATE dbo.orders o
SET o.comp_date = '2020-08-14', o.order_notes= 'bulk update'
WHERE o.order_no = 1000579;
```

Any advice much appreciated

Expecting to see a single SQL query
I have several thousands of records to update, above is just a small sample

Comment: Please post an example of what you have tried so far and what is not working.  You will be more likely to get a helpful answer if you do that :)

Comment: Insert into a temp table using `bcp` or `BULK INSERT` or `SqlBulkCopy` and then do a joined update. What did you try?

Comment: have posted what ive tried as requested, i simply do not know which other method to use

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couple minor things here. First, not all the order numbers in your example updates exist in your source data. Thats probably just a typo, so no biggie, but that's why in my final output those rows wind up not being updated.

Second, I had to switch around the dateformat because of where I live, but again, that's not really material to the solution, just making you aware of the fact that I did it.

Basically you need to get the rows you want to use for your update in some table-like structure. That can be a temporary table (table beginning with a `#`), a permanent table (if you think you'll need to do something like this over and over again) or, as I've done here, a Common Table Expression (aka CTE) (which is basically just defining a set of rows that only exists for the query which follows it. Load the CTE up with the row constructors you want to update, then join your orders table with the CTE and perform your update.

Several thousand rows should be just find to `union all` together in a CTE like this. If you get up into, say, 10-100 thousand rows, you might want to look into something like SSIS, BCP, or the Import/Export wizard to load the rows into a persisted table.

```
/*****************************
Simulate Orders Table 
(pretending this is your persisted table you want to update)
*****************************/
drop table if exists #orders
create table #orders
(
    OrderNo int not null,
    CompDate date not null default '01/01/1900',
    OrderNotes varchar(1000) null
)

insert into #orders
(
    OrderNo
)
values
    (1000579),
    (1000578),
    (1005077),
    (1000576),
    (1000575),
    (1000574),
    (1000573),
    (1000572),
    (1000571)

/*****************************
Do the Update
*****************************/
;with src 
(
    OrderNo,
    CompDate,
    OrderNotes
)
as
(
    select 1000579, '08/14/2020', 'bulk update'
    union all select 1000578, '08/29/2019', 'bulk update'
    union all select 1005077, '06/02/2019', 'bulk update'
    union all select 1005706, '06/03/2019', 'bulk update'
    union all select 1005750, '06/29/2019', 'bulk update'
    union all select 1000574, '06/25/2019', 'bulk update'
    union all select 1000573, '07/24/2019', 'bulk update'
    union all select 1000572, '07/24/2019', 'bulk update'
    union all select 1000571, '07/03/2019', 'bulk update'
)
update t
set CompDate = s.CompDate,
    OrderNotes = s.OrderNotes
from #orders t
inner join src s
    on t.OrderNo = s.OrderNo

select top 1000 *
from #orders
```

Comment: thank you for taking time to reply, i will have a play. i did just notice that in the order notes colum i have some text, so they aren't all NULL. I dont know if that will effect above solution, sorry i should have spotted that earlier, thank you

Comment: Thank you it worked. only thing i noted that i changed was to use "from orders t" not "from temp #orders t" so the data could be written to the target db and not the temp one! thanks, very useful solution.